# Identifying a subclass with Swift Generics works with custom class but not with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, generics, uigesturerecognizer, xcode7

There's something I wanted to do in swift, but I couldn't figure out how to achieve it, that is to remove gesture recognisers given a Class Type, here's my code (and example), i'm using swift 2.0 in Xcode 7 beta 5:

I have 3 classes that inherits from UITapGestureRecognizer

```
class GestureONE: UIGestureRecognizer { /*...*/ }
class GestureTWO: UIGestureRecognizer { /*...*/ }
class GestureTHREE: UIGestureRecognizer { /*...*/ }
```

Add them to a view

```
var gesture1 =     GestureONE()
var gesture11 =    GestureONE()
var gesture2 =     GestureTWO()
var gesture22 =    GestureTWO()
var gesture222 =   GestureTWO()
var gesture3 =     GestureTHREE()

var myView = UIView()
myView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture1)
myView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture11)
myView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture2)
myView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture22)
myView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture222)
myView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture3)
```

I print the object:

```
print(myView.gestureRecognizers!)
// playground prints "[<__lldb_expr_224.TapONE: 0x7fab52c20b40; baseClass = UITapGestureRecognizer; state = Possible; view = <UIView 0x7fab52d259c0>>, <__lldb_expr_224.TapONE: 0x7fab52d21250; baseClass = UITapGestureRecognizer; state = Possible; view = <UIView 0x7fab52d259c0>>, <__lldb_expr_224.TapTWO: 0x7fab52d24a60; baseClass = UITapGestureRecognizer; state = Possible; view = <UIView 0x7fab52d259c0>>, <__lldb_expr_224.TapTWO: 0x7fab52c21130; baseClass = UITapGestureRecognizer; state = Possible; view = <UIView 0x7fab52d259c0>>, <__lldb_expr_224.TapTWO: 0x7fab52e13260; baseClass = UITapGestureRecognizer; state = Possible; view = <UIView 0x7fab52d259c0>>, <__lldb_expr_224.TapTHREE: 0x7fab52c21410; baseClass = UITapGestureRecognizer; state = Possible; view = <UIView 0x7fab52d259c0>>]"
```

Have this extension I made with a generic function

```
extension UIView {
    func removeGestureRecognizers<T: UIGestureRecognizer>(type: T.Type) {
        if let gestures = self.gestureRecognizers {
            for gesture in gestures {
                if gesture is T {
                    removeGestureRecognizer(gesture)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I use it

```
myView.gestureRecognizers?.count // Prints 6
myView.removeGestureRecognizers(GestureTWO)
myView.gestureRecognizers?.count // Prints 0
```

Is removing all of the gestures D:

And here's an experiment with custom classes

```
//** TEST WITH ANIMALS*//
class Animal { /*...*/ }

class Dog: Animal { /*...*/ }
class Cat: Animal { /*...*/ }
class Hipo: Animal { /*...*/ }

class Zoo {
    var animals = [Animal]()
}

var zoo = Zoo()

var dog1 = Dog()
var cat1 = Cat()
var cat2 = Cat()
var cat3 = Cat()
var hipo1 = Hipo()
var hipo2 = Hipo()

zoo.animals.append(dog1)
zoo.animals.append(cat1)
zoo.animals.append(cat2)
zoo.animals.append(cat3)
zoo.animals.append(hipo1)
zoo.animals.append(hipo2)

print(zoo.animals)
//playground prints "[Dog, Cat, Cat, Cat, Hipo, Hipo]"

extension Zoo {
    func removeAnimalType<T: Animal>(type: T.Type) {
        for (index, animal) in animals.enumerate() {
            if animal is T {
                animals.removeAtIndex(index)
            }
        }
    }
}

zoo.animals.count // prints 6
zoo.removeAnimalType(Cat)
zoo.animals.count // prints 3
```

It's actually removing the classes it should :D

What am I missing with the UIGestureRecognizer's? I ended up with a workaround making a function that has no generics (boring) like this:

```
extension UIView {
    func removeActionsTapGestureRecognizer() {
        if let gestures = self.gestureRecognizers {
            gestures.map({
                if $0 is ActionsTapGestureRecognizer {
                    self.removeGestureRecognizer($0)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This works of course, but still I would like to have a real solution

I appreciate your help!!

Note: First question I ask here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

Use `dynamicType` to check the runtime type of each gesture recognizer against your `type` parameter.

---

Great question. It looks like you're encountering a scenario where the difference between Objective-C's dynamic typing and Swift's static typing becomes clear.

In Swift, `SomeType.Type` is the metatype type of a type, which essentially allows you to specify a compile-time type parameter. But this might not be the same as the type at runtime.

```
class BaseClass { ... }
class SubClass: BaseClass { ... }

let object: BaseClass = SubClass()
```

In the example above, `object`'s compile-time class is `BaseClass`, but at runtime, it is `SubClass`. You can check the runtime class with `dynamicType`:

```
print(object.dynamicType)
// prints "SubClass"
```

So why does that matter? As you saw with your `Animal` test, things behaved as you expected: your method takes an argument whose type is a metatype type of an `Animal` subclass, and then you only remove animals that conform to that type. The compiler knows that `T` can be any particular subclass of `Animal`. But if you specify an Objective-C type (`UIGestureRecognizer`), the compiler dips its toes into the uncertain world of Objective-C dynamic typing, and things get a little less predictable until runtime.

*I must warn you that I'm a bit wooly on the details here... I don't know the specifics of how the compiler/runtime treats generics when mixing the worlds of Swift & Objective-C. Perhaps somebody with some better knowledge of the subject could chip in and elucidate!*

As a comparison, let's just quickly try a variation of your method where the compiler can steer a bit further clear of the Objective-C world:

```
class SwiftGesture: UIGestureRecognizer {}

class GestureONE: SwiftGesture {}
class GestureTWO: SwiftGesture {}
class GestureTHREE: SwiftGesture {}

extension UIView {
    func removeGestureRecognizersOfType<T: SwiftGesture>(type: T.Type) {
        guard let gestureRecognizers = self.gestureRecognizers else { return }
        for case let gesture as T in gestureRecognizers {
            self.removeGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        }
    }
}

myView.removeGestureRecognizers(GestureTWO)
```

With the above code, only `GestureTWO` instances will be removed, which is what we want, if only for Swift types. The Swift compiler can look at this generic method declaration without concerning itself with Objective-C types.

Fortunately, as discussed above, Swift is capable of inspecting the runtime type of an object, using `dynamicType`. With this knowledge, it only takes a minor tweak to make your method work with Objective-C types:

```
func removeGestureRecognizersOfType<T: UIGestureRecognizer>(type: T.Type) {
    guard let gestureRecognizers = self.gestureRecognizers else { return }
    for case let gesture in gestureRecognizers where gesture.dynamicType == type {
        self.removeGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
}
```

The for loop binds to the `gesture` variable only gesture recognizers whose *runtime* type is equal to the passed in metatype type value, so we successfully remove only the specified type of gesture recognizers.

Comment: Great answer!! also thanks for the `SwiftGesture` example and the `for case let` tip!!